# Unable to insert data into database in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql

[image: error screenshot]

I am getting the given error when inserting data into the database. The query is fine. I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Obligatory: Please protect your code against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  It's *very* dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `(`, `)`, `[` and `]`:

```
Insert into [User] (Name, Uid) values ('"+tb1.Text+"', '"+tb1.Text+"')";
```

---

Note the use of '[' and ']' around the reserved word User.  And, like @marc_s states: "One should really use parametrized queries in order to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)"

**Check [THIS](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) for more info.**

Comment: And again: one should really use **parametrized queries** in order to avoid SQL Injection .....

Comment: Or, you could always see **[this](http://xkcd.com/327/)** for more info =)

Answer (score 10):

3 things are wrong here.

---

Add brackets around your table name as it is a keyword:

```
INSERT INTO [User]
```

Try to avoid using keywords when naming objects in future. It can save a lot of headaches in the long run!

**[View reserved keywords here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)**

---

Add brackets around your values, so your query is in the form of:

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (@ParamA, @ParamB)
```

---

Most importantly (as its the 1 error you won't get prompted about, but will suffer for in the long run), parametize your queries. This will avoid **[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** and should be common practice when writing any SQL Query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [User] (Name, Uid) values (@Name, @Uid)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Nvarchar).Value = tb1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Uid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb1.Text;
```

Answer (score 3):

`User` is a keyword. You can use reserved keywords by surrounding them with brackets `[]`. And you should enclose the values with parentheses `()`.

Try the following:

```
str = "Insert into [User] (Name, Uid) values
       ('" + tb1.Text + "', '" + tb1.Text + "')";
```

Or, more readable:

```
str = String.Format("Insert into [User] (Name, Uid) values ('{0}', '{1}')",
                    tb1.Text, tb2.Text);
```

Also, as jadarnel27 commented, please consider using parameterized SQL to prevent [SQL injection attacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(v=sql.80).aspx